# How to add conditions to a linear system of equation

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, vectors, systems-of-equations

I am quite confused about solving multi-variable equation systems with less than necessary lines. I understand I need to add more conditions but I just can't figure out how :

I have a set of three vectors (in $2$ dimensions), and by performing only rotations, I would like to obtain a given vector (target):

For example : $v_1 = (x_1, y_1), v_2 = (x_2, y_2), v_3 = (x_3, y_3)$ and $v_t = (x_t, y_t)$

let's call $rot_1, rot_2, rot_3$ three usual rotation matrices in $2D$ Euclidian space.

Then, my system is :

$\ rot_1 \times v_1 + rot_2 \times v_2 + rot_3 \times v_3 = v_t$

And I want to find the three corresponding angles: $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$

Of course, this system has infinitely many solutions, so I would like to restrict it by adding the following condition : $f : v_1, v_2, v_3 \to z \in \Re, f(rot_1 \times v_1, rot_2 \times v_2, rot_3 \times v_3) = min(f)$.

But I just don't know how to combine them together, am I doing it completely wrong ? I tried to take the problem from the math perspective instead of trying to brute force it by computer but for now it looks like a dead end.

Sorry, I realized my question is quite confusing, and really lacks details. I thank you all for your advices.

Comment: If the angles are your unkowns, how is a function on the vectors $f(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ an additional condition?

Comment: Furthermore, please use mathjax and remove the ODE tag.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, and sorry the for the unclear question.
I did my best to make it more readable and understandable.

Comment: You really only have at most two degrees of freedom: your problem is equivalent to finding respective points on the circles $x^2+y^2=\lVert v_1\rVert^2$ and $(x-x_t)^2+(y-y_t)^2=\lVert v_2\rVert^2$ that are a distance of $\lVert v_3\rVert$ apart. This looks like a Lagrange multiplier problem: minimize $f$ subject to this constraint.

Comment: @amd I am not familiar with Lagrange multiplier yet, what would be the function $f$ here ? I guess we need to measure the distance between the points of each circle but I have no idea of how to do so without a fixed $x$ and $y$ .

Comment: This mysterious function $f$ comes directly from your question. It’s up to you to come up with this function since you haven’t described any other criteria for acceptable solutions in your question.